# Why are my password validation rules not working?

Tags: asp.net-core

I configured the Password Validation Rules in the startup class services.AddIdentity<> section, but it does not work. I used Asp Core Identity API such that:

```
Password.RequiredLength = 8
```

but I need a password with an arbitrary length in my project.

This is the content of my current files (i.e. CreateController and StartUp.cs)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDBContext>(options     =>options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration["ConnectionStrings:IdentityConnection"]
            ));
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(opts => {
              opts.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
              opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
              opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
              opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
              opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDBContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}


public async Task<IActionResult> Create(UserCreateVM model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AppUser user = new AppUser
            {
                UserName = model.Name,
                Email = model.Email,
            };

            IdentityResult Result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);

            if(Result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            else
            {
                foreach (var item in Result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", item.Description);
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably have another setting of password validation that conflicts with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I Edit this Line :

```
IdentityResult Result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
```

to :

```
IdentityResult Result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user,model.Password);
```

and problem Solved.